# How can I make my discord bot only send a message if a user starts typing in a specific channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Not sure What I am doing wrong here. I am trying to get my bot to only send this message if the user starts typing in the defined channel. I don't get errors the bot just doesn't send a message. Help Please!

```
bot.on("typingStart", (channel, user) => {

const bot_channel =  "812180709401247658"

if (channel.id = bot_channel.id) {
     message.send('wrong channel');
}

});
```

I have also tried:

```
bot.on("typingStart", (message , channel) => {

const bot_channel =  "812180709401247658"

if (channel.id === bot_channel.id) {
    message.send('wrong channel');
}

});
```

Comment: Hey! Was this solved on your end? Just want to see if I can replicate this code to create one on my end. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A single equals sign `=` is assignment. To perform comparison in JavaScript, use either the double equals sign or the triple equals sign. For most cases of comparison, you *should* use `===`. Your code should look like this then:

```js
bot.on("typingStart", (channel, user) => {
  const bot_channel =  "812180709401247658"
  if (channel.id === bot_channel.id) {
    message.send('wrong channel');
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately, it still does nothing.

Comment: Also, thanks for explaining the assignment vs comparison!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
bot.on("typingStart", (message, channel) => {

  const channel = "812180709401247658"

  if (message.channel.id != channel) {
      return message.channel.send('You can only use this command in <#' + channel + '>');
  }

});
```

if it still does not work use this

```
bot.on("message", (message) => {

  const channel = "812180709401247658"

  if (message.channel.id != channel) {
      return message.channel.send('You can only use this command in <#' + channel + '>');
  }

});
```

**"!=" means isn't, so if channel isn't the one you selected it will return the message, simple**